# Streamlining development process of Linux C++ CLI app

Tags: c++, development-process, shell

On Linux Mint 19 with C++ compiler version: **`g++-8 (...) 8.2.0`**

I am compiling and running my project named: **getPixelColor**

---

Using a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
g++-8 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -o getPixelColor getPixelColor.cpp -lX11 && ./getPixelColor "${@}"
```

Finally, I defined a personal alias:

```sh
alias work-pixel='watch -n 1 /home/vlastimil/Development/getPixelColor/cpp/compileRun 0 0'
```

And work inside Visual Studio Code like that:

[image: VS Code with Terminal]

---

### Question

Did I streamline the development process to 100%, or is there yet some space for improvements?

Comment: I don't think there's a "correct" answer.  It seems to be working for you, so yes.  You might consider trying a simple make file next instead of the shell script, just for learning purposes.

Comment: You may want to setup VSC in a way you can start the build process by a shortcut, and in case of compiling errors, it shows you directly the place of errors. [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code).

Comment: @DocBrown I did not know that, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [GrandmasterB](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/897/grandmasterb), I realized that for C++ projects, it is ordinary to add Makefile to make things even easier and streamlined.

---

### `Makefile`

This is quite new to me. I like the way things get dependent there. Awesome way to go.

```
COORDS ?= 0 0

CXX := g++-8
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors
LDLIBS := -lX11
RM := rm -f

BIN := getPixelColor
SRC := $(BIN).cpp

$(BIN): $(SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(BIN) $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN)

.PHONY: run
run: $(BIN)
    ./$(BIN) $(COORDS)
```

---

### `compileRun` (POSIX shell script)

This file serves for an infinite loop of constant (compiling and) running the with signal failsafes. Can be given X, Y coordinates optionally.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -o nounset

trap 'cleanup' HUP INT QUIT ABRT TERM

cleanup()
{
    printf '\n%s\n' 'Cleaning up... Exiting.' 1>&2
    make -s clean
    exit 1
}

while true
do
    clear
    make -s clean

    if [ "${#}" -eq 2 ]
    then
        COORDS="${*}" make run
    else
        make run
    fi

    sleep 5s
done
```

It looks neater now. Thank you for guidance!

Comment: Make file looks good!

Comment: @GrandmasterB Thank you! I've done maybe too many edits already. I hope it's fine now.

Comment: You're welcome!  Looks like you got it.